# selectedIndexPath in sectioned UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

As you can see in the picture linked below, when I select the first row, the selected row index returns 0. When I select the second row it also returns 0 and when I select the third row it returns 1.

Why is this and how can I determine what is actually selected?

[picture](http://s5.picofile.com/file/8156035284/Screen_Shot_2014_12_08_at_7_20_51_AM.png)

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSIndexPath *selectedRowIndexPath = [tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    int selectedSection = selectedRowIndexPath.section;

    NSInteger i =0;
    for (NSInteger j = 0; j <= selectedSection; ++j)
    {
        for (i=0; i < [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:j]; ++i)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please place the picture you link at http://s5.picofile.com/file/8156035284/Screen_Shot_2014_12_08_at_7_20_51_AM.png into being actually displayed in the question. It is better to not have such things dependent on non-stackoverflow resources as they can disappear making the question much less understandable in the future. To do this, edit the question and click on the image icon that is 3 icons to the right of the one you clicked on to add the link. You can then specify the link as a web based location. I did not just edit it in as copyright does not permit _me_ to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you have to look at the sections.

It is indeed first row but of the section 0, section 1 etc.

To generalize, you have rows 0 as much as you have sections(assuming you have rows in each section).

Section 0(Let say A since you have something like phone book):

- Abraham Lincoln(row 0)
- Aladin with the lattern(row 1)
- Abrakadabra(Row 2)

Section 1(Letter b)

- Bob(row 0)
- Brandley(row 1)

Section 2(letter c):

- Cindy(row 0)
- Cinemon(row 1)
- Cayonara(row 2)

Code:

```
NSInteger rowNumber = 0;

for (NSInteger i = 0; i < indexPath.section; i++) {
    rowNumber += [self tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:i];
}

rowNumber += indexPath.row;
```

Comment: It is right... if you need very first row then you have to check 
indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0. So in your case you have to check both section and row

Comment: but i have 28 section in my table view (the picture is sample), please put an example

Comment: exacly i have a phone book with dynamic sections and. e.g i whant when i select Cinemon it's return 5

Comment: Cinemon is not 5, Cindy is 5 :) Cinemon is 6 but never mind. you can do the following: for each section sum the number of rows and then add the current row

Answer (score 0):

They are different section.
Row begin with index 0 in every section.
IndexPath has two component:section and row.